# Active Adblock Plus shows weird error in Chrome JS Console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, malware, adblock

Every page i browse with chrome shows this error in the console:

extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8

Error in event handler for (unknown): SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Failed to parse the rule '::content #GoogleLeaderBoardAdUnit, ::content .insert_advertisement, ::content .ads-fif, ::content a[href^="http://www.gamebookers.com/cgi-bin/intro.cgi?], ::content .ads324-wrapper, ::content #rhsadvert, ::content .ad-lead, ::content #gtv_tabSponsor, ::content #adsense1, ::content #ap_adframe, ::content #adv_google_300, ::content #iqd_rightAd, ::content #bottom-side-ad, ::content #right_side_bar_ami_ad, ::content .ipm-sidebar-ad-middle, ::content .topad-area, ::content #advertising_728, ::content .logo_AdChoices, ::content #right-uppder-adverts-container, ::content .article_ad { display: none !important; }'. at chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/include.preload.js:345:25handler @ extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8exports.handle @ extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:100EventImpl.dispatch_ @ extensions::event_bindings:384EventImpl.dispatch @ extensions::event_bindings:401propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19$Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:94dispatchOnMessage @ extensions::messaging:316

if i deactivate Adblock Plus (1.9.3) the erros msg is gone. If i activate Adblock Plus the Error shows up, even if every other extension is deactivated. I am worried adblock is not the problem, but makes the problem visible.

Also a project I just finished got declined by Google Adwords with the reason "Malware". Im waiting for a callback from adwords tech support for more details.

I am worried that my system or browser is infected with some sort of malware which already found its way into my web projects. And i have now idea what to do about it.

I am running the latest Chrome on Yosemite 10.10.5

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by an invalid CSS selector in one of the EasyList filters that are being used in Adblock Plus. It was fixed by one of the EasyList authors [on October 14](https://hg.adblockplus.org/easylist/rev/570ed2c43427).

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is an error that is caused by Adblock Plus.  Others on the site have reported the same error.  See the answer below.  Apparently Adblock Plus is causing problems with the CSSStyleSheet.insertRule() call.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133565/jquery-error-never-seen-before